# Can a variable representing a script name be passed to the "action" attribute of a form?

Tags: php, action

I'm not sure if this can be done just in php, but I am trying to use a dropdown form to allow the user to select one of multiple scripts to run. Here is a simple example (it does not run because it isn't processing the "scriptSelect" variable properly.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="gateway" action= "scriptSelect" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<th>Select Script:
<select name="scriptSelect" >
<option value="">Please make a selection</option>
<option value="scripta.php">scripta.php</option>
<option value="scriptb.php">scriptb.php</option>
</th>
<td><input name="update" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
<td><input name="resetForm" id="resetForm" type="reset" value="Reset Form"></td>
</fieldset></form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I am open to other solutions to this but I'm kinda new so I'm trying to keep it simple

Comment: You need Javascript.

Comment: Slaks do you mean Javascipt for the "action" attribute of the form or something different?

Comment: I mean use Javascript code to change it.

Comment: ok thanks @SLaks   I'll do some research

Comment: would you mind giving me a basic example.  I'm not understanding what I'm finding at the moment